# Filtering multiple variables with a single negative logical criterion in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have just started using `dplyr` and have gone through the vignette and it does not have an example that matches my requirements.  I cannot work out how to `filter()` multiple variables in a dataframe with a statement equivalent to 'remove all cases where columnX equals 'i' or columnY equals 'ii' . Say we have this dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(n = rep(1:4,4), l = rep(letters[1:4], each = 4))
```

I want to remove all cases that are either n = 1 or l = "a". I can do this with standard subsetting with this command.

```
df[-which(df$n == 1 | df$l == "a"),]
```

Using `filter` I can get rid of all the 1's with

```
filter(df, !n == 1)
```

or

```
filter(df, n != 1)
```

and the same for the "a"s

But if I try to combine them like so

```
filter(df, !n == 1 | !l == "a")
```

or

```
filter(df, n != 1 | l != "a")
```

or

```
filter(df, !n == 1 | l == "a")
```

it seems like the 'or' function `|` doesn't work the same way in dplyr.

Or maybe I'm just missing something very obvious.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `filter(df, !(n==1|l=="a"))`

Comment: thank you the extra `()` around the logical statement was what I was after.

Comment: See `?Syntax` for operator precedence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want neither case to occur, you have to write it like this:

```
df %>% filter(!(n == 1 | l == "a"))
```

//

As for your examples,

```
df %>% filter(n != 1 | l != "a")
```

is equivalent to

```
df %>% filter(!n == 1 | !l == "a")
```

which, using De Morgan's law that `(!(a & b)) = (!a | !b)`, is the same as:

```
df %>% filter(! (n == 1 & l == "a"))
```

and filters out all rows where both conditions are satisfied at the same time.

Your example of

```
df %>% filter(!n == 1 | l == "a")
```

will only prohibit cases where `n == 1` and `l != "a"` occur on the same row, so (1,b); (1,c) and (1,d) are missing from the dataframe. (notation: (n,l))

Answer (score 1):

you can use `df[(df$n != 1 | df$l !="a"),]` for subsetting, which effectively gets rid of the first row in your example, leaving you with 15 rows.

if you use the same with dplyr, it returns the same number of records, which can be checked with

```
   df %>% 
    filter(n != 1 | l != "a") %>% 
    dim() %>% 
    assertthat::are_equal(dim(df[(df$n != 1 | df$l !="a"),]))
```

This gets rid of all rows where both conditions are true.

On the other hand, if you want to exclude cases where any of the conditions are true, you can use `df %>% filter(!(n == 1 | l == "a"))`, which returns 9 rows, excluding all rows where any one condition is true.

Revisiting [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) may be helpful.